# How to merge incorrect spelling tag with correct

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

There is a tag mis-spelled...
natural-diseasters
Which should be merged with natural-disasters
or maybe disaster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be incorrect in assuming that the moderators (or others) would fix these.  Is that not the case?  I can see merging differences in spelling (eg. color and colour) to account for country-based differences in spelling, but spelling errors should be corrected as some level or flagged by the community to the mods.

Comment: that was my thought. I changed the questio I saw using incorrect tag. but I think there were other questions using it. maybe I shoudl track them down and then the mods would have clear path.

Comment: mods will fix typos when they see them, they have to notice the problem first though :) so yes, please do flag typos and variant spellings

Comment: How does one flag tags btw?

Answer (score 3):

OK, I've merged the tags -- you can also suggest a synonym for a tag on the tag's page in the future.