# Flagging tag for moderator attention?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed

How do I flag a Tag for moderator attention?

I saw the meta question on how to [Merge incorrect spelling tags with correct](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/426/how-to-merge-incorrect-spelling-tag-with-correct).  In the answer to that question, it was said to flag the tag for moderator attention in order to have corrections made.

I am asking this specifically because a series of tags are related, but I have no way to suggest synonyms due to my level of reputation.

There is a Tag called "Generalisation".  It has been used for about 11 questions, and has 3 followers.  There is another Tag, "Generalization".  They are both spelling variations, and should likely be synonyms.

In addition, another Tag, "Generalize", has been added as a synonym to "Generalisation", but could also logically be added as a synonym to "Generalization"

I do not have enough reputation points to suggest one as a synonym to the other, and I cannot find a better way to flag these for moderator attention.  If I'm just not seeing the place to flag those, let me know!

Comment: As far as I can tell "Generalisation" is just BE and not misspelled.

Comment: @underdark - Edited question to remove spelling error references, but question of how to flag a tag for moderator attention, based on referenced question, still applies.

Comment: @underdark British English allows words ending in `-ization` and `-ize`. My Oxford English dictionary has `generalize (also ise)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is complicated because the interface varies slightly according to reputation.

On a sister site where I have less rep, one successful approach for me begins with the [tags page](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags).  There, at the lower left (below the tag listing) you will find a [tag synonyms link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms).  Hovering the mouse over any tag listed on that page brings a pop-up menu including a "synonyms" item: choose that and follow the instructions.  You should get an option to "suggest" a tag synonym.

Here, because I am a moderator--or perhaps because of different designs among sites--, a slightly different interface is presented.  The "synonyms" item does not appear on the hover menu, but there is a [Create a Tag Synonym link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/admin/create-tag-synonym) presented near the top of the page.  I suspect that only mods (and perhaps high rep users) can use that link, though.

Sometimes people just flag a question where one or more problematic tags appears and make their suggestion that way.  It's not the approved mechanism to suggest a synonym, but it's not a whole lot more work for the mods to handle, either, provided only one or two flags are created that way.  When you have a lot of suggestions to make, please try to work through the official mechanisms.

Comment: I can see that the interface changes based on reputation.  I, for example, do not have the option to "suggest" a tag synonym, because I do not yet have 2500 reputation.  Based on what you have said, it looks like my only option would be what you suggested in the first part of your last paragraph, as the "official' mechanisms are not available to me, or any other low rep users who may come across an obvious issue.

Comment: Though this didn't really come up with a complete answer for low reputation users who want to flag a tag for moderator attention, I think it might be because there isn't really a process, so I've marked as accepted.  @whuber would you please do me a favor and add "generalization" as a synonym to "generalisation"?  Thanks for this, and taking the time to answer, it is much appreciated.